# Calculating FPS in delphi Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, frame-rate

I'm using two timers for that

```
Timer1.Interval = 1;
Timer2.Interval = 1000;

var
FPS: Integer = 0;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Inc(FPS);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := IntToStr(FPS) + 'FPS';
  FPS := 0;
end;
```

Im getting 65 FPS.

How accurate is that and What is the most right/accurate way to calculate FPS(Frame per second)?

Comment: Are you trying to measure FPS through Firemonkey HD or 3D form?

Answer (score 2):

You don't calculate FPS here. This code counts events of 1 ms-period Windows timer per second. Note that 1 millisecond is too short period for Window timer, because typical Windows response time (don't know exact English word for it) is 10-20 milliseconds (65 events =~ 15 ms). So in Windows you can *measure* time interval with good precision, but it is much harder to guarantee exact time of event triggering.

To calculate FPS, you have to count needed events during exactly measured time (read about QueryPerformanceCounter function etc).

Comment: Is there a relation between timer event and FPS? I made a test of rotating 1000 cubes (on timer1 event) and i get between 20-30 events, so the new event does not execute until the prevoius one finsh. doesn't that give us the fps?

Comment: Yes, that gives us FPS of graphic events, initiated by this timer. But these FPS are not real FPS - you'd better to draw independently from any timer